# How to convert a `Stream` into imperative read operations

Tags: scala, fs2

I have a `Stream[F,A]` and I need to convert it into the following more "primitive streaming interface" in order to be consumed by a part of the codebase that is not `fs2` aware:

```
trait PrimitiveStreamRepr[F[_]] {
  def read:  F[Option[A]]
  def close: F[Unit]
}
```

How would I go about doing that?
Maybe the answer is that such a transformation is not possible and once you wrap a java streaming interface into a `fs2.Stream` it can longer be "converted" back into a "java style" streaming interface, one must bubble the `Stream` all the way to the top level where it can be piped to some `Sink` and `run`.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what you sort of suggesting is the stepping through the stream.

The stepping in the stream is still implemented, and what you suggest will be possible if the whole PrimitiveStreamRepr will be wrapped with Stream, which unlikely is what you want.

As for interfacing with legacy code please see async._ package for various queues and signals available.

Sorry I can't help you more, I will need particullar case in legacy code you try to solve.

Essentially fs2._ integrates very well with legacy code, does not matter if it is sync or async. However we do not expose internal functionality that will eventually end up in non-resource safe code.